# How to set color using integer?

Tags: android-layout, colors, view, setbackground

How can i convert color code in integer ex: 13369395 to android specific. Since 13369395 is also an integer i tried doing

```
mainLayout.setTextColor(13369395);
```

but its not working.

I also tried converting 13369395 to hexadecimal like:

```
mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(13369395 +"", 16)+0xFF000000);
```

but it also didn't help.

Answer (score 8):

I got the solution. Just a work around with Hexadecimal as below:

`Integer.toHexString(colour);`

Which returns the hexadecimal string for your integer, again if you just use it by

`mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(hexVal,16));`

it wont work. You need to add mask as

`mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000 + Integer.parseInt(hexVal,16));`

This has resolved the problem

Answer (score 8):

Try passing:

```
mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Answer (score 7):

The question is very old. Still this answer would help someone who search a way to set the color directly as an integer.

If you look at the android documentation, the constant value for white is -1 and black is -16777216. (i.e.) the whole color int value range is (-1 to -16777216). So you can simply add the integer value to -16777216.

For example if you want to set color white whose decimal representation is 16777215 (0xffffff), then 16777215 - 16777216 will give you -1 the color constant for black in android.

Answer (score -2):

You can directly take hexadecimal code.For example

mainLayout.setBackgroundColor( #0BB5FF);

Comment: I got the solution. Just a work around with Hexadecimal as below: Integer.toHexString(colour); which returns the hexadecimal string for your integer, again if you just use it by mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(hexVal,16)); it wont work. You need to add mask as  mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000 + Integer.parseInt(hexVal,16)); This has resolved the problem. Thanks

Comment: mainLayout.setBackgroundColor( #0BB5FF); This is not supported as of Java 1.6