# How to convert Int value to COLOR in Android (with Kotlin or Java)?

Tags: android, kotlin, graphics, colors, decimal

I searched a lot but cannot find a solution.

From the API it returns an Int as a color value 2813300.
This is a tone of Green [LiNK to COLOR](https://convertingcolors.com/android-color-2813300.html?search=Android(2813300))

I try to use this Int as a Color in my project but I cannot convert it to android.graphics.Color.

When I try to use the int it is not working.

How can I convert these numbers to Color?

Examples:

RED = 16711936 ([Link](https://convertingcolors.com/android-color-16711936.html?search=Android(16711936)))

GREEN = 2813300 ([Link](https://convertingcolors.com/android-color-2813300.html?search=Android(2813300)))

Comment: Have you tried `Color.valueOf(..longvalue..)`

Comment: Show the code that isn’t working for you.

Answer (score 5):

Integer.toString will convert your int value to Hex value

```
 Integer.toString(2813300, 16)
```

result :

```
2AED74
```

And you can use the Hex color like this :

```
String Hex  = Integer.toString(2813300, 16);
myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + Hex));
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, I found what I did wrong.

My code was calling another method which gets the color from resources when I use `2813300` it could not be found in resources.

Below code was not working

```
myLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
```

When I changed it to below it worked.

```
myLayout.setBackground(2813300-1677216, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
```

([answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36126486/7513402)) - if you want to know why i used `-16777216` visit [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36126486/7513402)

```
var color = 2813300 - 16777216
dialogBody.background.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
```

But also the previous answer is perfect to use. Thank you Anehme